# Displaying data on row of submit button

Tags: php, html, form-submit

Basically I have a table that is being used to display data from an sql table.

Each row in the database is looped through so each row in the database is also displayed on a new row in the html table.

I have a submit button included in the loop which is displayed in the last column of each row.

What I want is when one of the submit buttons are pressed, the data on that specific row is stored and the displayed on the next page which is the forms action.

I'm not sure if this is possible the way I have done it or if I need a unique identifier for each submit button.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I have got the rows displaying with a submit button  at the end of each row. When the submit button is clicked the next page opens but I need a way to display the specific data in the row of the submit button that was clicked on the new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well each row in the sql should have a unique identifier, use this identifier to distinguish which row of the html table that the user selected.

simply, on the submit button have a post or get value of that unique identifier.

When the next page is loaded, use $_GET or $_POST to recieve that unique identifier, use SQL to find the data of that row, and then display it to the html at the top of the new page.

I believe that is what you are asking. Since you didnt ask for specific code.

**EDIT:**
If you want to use a get, use a simple anchor: just have the id in the url

```
<a href="tablepage.php?rowid=$rowid">Submit</a>
```

on the new page that links to, you just use

```
$id=intval($_GET['rowid']) //the intval is for verification security
```

or if you want to use a post, use a form

```
<form name="table" action="/tablepage.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> //this is the submit button, use a div to change its look
<input type="hidden" name="post" value="$rowid" />   //this contains the unique id in the post
</form>
```

and on the next page you get the post value through

```
  $id=intval($_POST['rowid'])
```

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I'm trying to achieve.
The unique indentifer (primary key) for the rows I'm displaying is regNumber. I'm not sure how to link the submit button to the specific row it is on in code.

Comment: use this identifier to distinguish which row of the html table that the user selected.
simply, on the submit button have a post or get value of that unique identifier.
Sorry I am unsure how to do this part, do you have any code examples?

Comment: i added an example to the original answer